# jquery selector on attribute with () in value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

given is the following lists (simplified):

```
<ul id="items">
  <li PK1="1" PK2="abc">value1</li>
  <li PK1="2" PK2="abc">value2</li>
  <li PK1="3" PK2="def(1)">value3</li>
  <li PK1="4" PK2="def(1)">value4</li>
</ul>

<ul id="types">
  <li PK="abc">abc</li>
  <li PK="def(1)">def</li>
</ul>
```

When a user hovers over a listitem of list 'types' the corresponding items from list 'items' need to visual change.

The selector i use is:

```
sCrit += '[pk2=\'' + $(this).attr('pk') + '\']';
$('ul#items li' + sCrit).addClass('Highlight');
```

In the real example the page crashes (100% CPU) as soon as i hover over listitem def, because of the () in the attribute (confirmed). 
the PK values of list 'types' cannot be changed so that is not an option.

It seems the jquery parser is looking for something other than just the value of the attribute. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried escaping `()` with `\\`?

Comment: could you please provide a jsfiddle!?

Comment: Not getting your question, you are using shorthand operator to concatenate in scrit? and taking value of pk2 and assigning value to pk2? Can you plz explain via fiddle or so?

Comment: sorry, my bad. updated the code. I will try to get the real markup (which is quite different) into fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You attribute selection was not correct i think...i think your code need to be like this..

```
 var sCrit = '[PK2="' + $(this).attr('PK')+'"]';
 $('#types li' + sCrit).addClass('Highlight');
```

Comment: thanks, altough this was just a typo in the example code. didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var sCrit= '';
$('ul#items li').hover(function(){
  sCrit = '[pk="' + $(this).attr('pk2') + '"]';     
  $('ul#types li' + sCrit).addClass('Highlight');
});

$('ul#items li').mouseleave(function(){
  $('ul#types li' + sCrit).removeClass('Highlight');
});
```

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/ZNz4H/)

Comment: nope, still the same. perhaps I could not simplify the problem to this list. I am trying to make a fiddle right now but not with any succes right now

Comment: @amaters Did you check my fiddle demo? I think you need to highlight corresponding li in "types" when you go hover on li in "items" and de-highlight when mouse leaves right?